# Redirecting admin site custom button to views

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a custom button in django admin. I want to redirect it to my views.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
{{ block.super }}

<div class="submit-row list-group">
    <button type="button" title="download file" class="list-group-item active" name="download_file";">
        <span class="glyphicon step-backward"></span>
        <span class="text">Download file</span>
    </button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In this code the button works like save button and saves the data to my model but instead of saving it I want to redirect it to views and access the data in views.

Is there anyway I could do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you want like 
you select checkboxes in admin and then on clicking this download file button that file get's downloaded. Right?

Comment: @xxbinxx yes,that is it.

Comment: you'll have to do some extra work here. I'll suggest use a custom [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), this way you'll get the queryset and you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: let me know if you're OK with using list_filter